# Schtasks can't run .bat file in windows server 2003

Tags: user-accounts, python, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks, batch-file

I have a problem with running a `.bat` file in windows 2003. If I change the user to Admin, I can run it without any problem, but with SYSTEM as user, it will not run. The command is:

**SCHTASKS /Create /SC Weekly /TN Import /TR "\"c:\path\to\prog.bat" /D Monday /ST 10:00 /F /RU SYSTEM**

The `.bat` file opens `Python.exe` with a run file, and a configuration file, and the configuration file is placed in `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\`.

Hope you can help.

Comment: What does "will not run"mean? What error msgs (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't run it as System.** System was never intended to be used as an user anyways.